# How to add an additional theme to a Bootstrap web project?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using a theme from Bootstrap and would like to add a new un-styled theme page from the same site, which comes with it's own files:

```
css
--bootstrap.css
--bootstrap.min.css
--style.css
js
--bootstrap.js
--bootstrap.min.js
--jquery-1.11.0.js
newpage.html
```

As far as I can tell, only the `newpage.html` and the `style.css` files are different from what I already have from the current theme. I added the `newpage.html` and the `style.css` to my project. However, when I open the new page, the content is there, but it seems to be missing all of the css and the js components. I suspect it might be a path issue.
My project structure with the new files, looks like this (simplified):

```
css
--style.css
js
pages
--newpage.html
index.html
```

In the newpage.html file, the css and the js are linked like so:
`<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
`<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`
`<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>`
`<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`
All of these files are there and accounted for. When I linked to the new page, I had to use this path: `"./pages/newpage.html"`
 What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try traversing up the directory with all the paths you are trying to include, traversing is denoted as '..'

Example:

```
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: This was it! Thanks #arinh